# Database Design for Tracking Customer Information?

Tags: database-design

I have the beginnings of a customer database (in Access 2010) with mailing addresses. There are two raw data sources of mailing addresses (from other databases) that get uploaded into this customer database, and there are team members who enter new mailing addresses in a form as they receive them.

Right now, the database is just a container for these three data sources. The objective is to build a report indicating which address is the best known address for each customer at the time of the report. How can I do this?

I thought about standardizing all three data sources in some way and doing a massive UNION ALL and then selecting the latest dated address. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can design a table to contain more than one address for a person.

```
Mailing Address
---------------
Person ID
Mailing Address ID
Mailing Address
Mailing Address Source
Insert Time Stamp
```

The mailing address should be broken down into component fields.

The primary key is (Person ID, Mailing Address ID DESC).  The first row you select for a Person ID would be the most recent address.  Inserting a newer address would be done by incrementing the maximum Mailing Address ID for a person by 1, and then inserting the mailing address row.